# Xcode Don't Open MyProject

Tags: ios, xcode

when i click .xcworkspace file or .xcodeproj file foe opening my project Xcode always in the state of loading, and don't open my project, but i can open project file Separately. how can solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: any message error?.

Comment: close and open project again.

Comment: @LeangSocheat nothing, just when force Quit Xcode show this error : Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

Comment: take backup of project and remove unsaved document in ~/Library/Autosave Information.

Comment: Ok. let try to open other small project than open your project by file -> open recently -> your project. try this two or three time.

Comment: @KKRocks i am fore quit Xcode , restart Mac , shut Down Mac, project DriveData but still not running.

Comment: @KKRocks i do it but still in loading wait. What happens?:|

Comment: @ava let try my solution. how was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using the work space for CocaPods delete the .xcworkspace and delete the Drive data from your project then re create the xcworkspace by Pod install.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way without removing xcworkspace and reinstalling Pods:
Open from Finder (use `Show Package Contents`) `*.xcworkspace` or/and `*.xcodeproj` and delete folder `xcuserdata`

Comment: Thank you for that solution. Solve really annoying problem here: XCode crash always when I checkout of some branch.